# including reference of cordova.2.4.0.js to my index.html

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

hello evryone i have a strange problem using phonegap/cordova.
well i m trying to build an application with html and jquery mobile.
when i run a test emulator of my app it not working and i got the famaous error: the connection to the server was unsuccessful.(file:///androif_asset/www/index.html)

ok i learned all the doc about setting phonegap i tried all the answers here about the same problem without solving it.

what is strange is that when i forgot to include the link of reference to cordova.2.4.0.js in the head tag of my index.html and my app is running now on the emulator ....so i tried to include the linke to cordova.2.4.0.js and retest my app on the emulator i got the same errore as before ....so i decided to make two app with the same html content the fisrth one with a refference to cordova.2.4.0.js and the seconde one without the reference to cordova.2.4.0.js and the result was : app with reference to cordova.2.4.0.js not working
and app without a reference to cordova is working !!!!!

someone can explaine this please ??111

Comment: Please post your HTML code and image of your directory structure

Answer (score 0):

It would help a lot if you could post the source code.

The mentioned error appears due to slow application loads which trigger a timeout on Android.

To resolve this issue you have to configure the loadUrlTimeoutValue defined by super.setIntegerProperty. This property has to be set inside the activity java file.

ex: `super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 160000);`

For more information regarding this issue you may check this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/16) which is relevant to your issue.

I hope this helps.

Comment: i tried to add image and directory structure but it said that i have 10 reputation to be able to post its

Comment: really i'm very conffused itried other exemple from github and MDS applaud when i run the exemple project with emulator it not work but if i delet the link in the head tag that point to cordova.js and i run again the app working

Comment: im postiong my question in a different way...if my app is just a simple application with html and jquery mobile and will not  interact with native features (e.g. camera, gps, ...) do i have not include the reference script witch point to cordova.js in the head of my index.html??